# Apache rewritecond -U not working

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, rule

A rewrite condition of Apache is -U which is suppose to check if an URL is available.
In my environment I have different resources on different servers. So I'd like to check if a resource is available on server A, if not use server B. Locally I have no problems because -f is doing the trick and checks if the file exists on the local host.

So the question is: can anyone confirm that -U is (not) working and give me an example?

This is not working...

```
RewriteCond http://123.123.123.123:8080/resources/Php%{REQUEST_URI} -U
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://123.123.123.123:8080/resources/Php/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The `-U` does work only internally in the apache process. You cannot check if some remote URL is valid or not with this rule... you need to find other way hot to find out the correct server.

Anyway, you should know where the resources/URIs are and either write a rule to route the requests or write static mapping using [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).